# Making a bouncing effect using Tweener

Tags: gnome-shell, tweener, gnome-shell-extensions

I would like to bounce my actor on y-axis for two 
Seconds following a button release event.

I don't know how I can do that using Tweener.

Gnome shell 3.4.

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying that effect. Instead using Tweener (imports.gi.Tweener), I simply set the opacity of the object from 0 to 255 in 'easeQuadEffect'.

Answer (score 0):

[GPaste Integration](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/752/gpaste-integration/) does what you want. Inspecting [the code](https://github.com/awamper/gpaste-integration) may be informative.

Search for "Tweener" in the gpaste_integration.js file.